# Landscape - "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Tags: apt, server, 18.04, landscape

The following occurs when trying to configure Landscape Server 18.03 on a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 18.04:

```
[user]@[server]:~$ sudo apt install landscape-server-quickstart
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 landscape-server-quickstart : Depends: landscape-server (>= 18.03- 
0ubuntu18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: postgresql-10-debversion but it is 
not installable or
                                        postgresql-9.5-debversion but it is 
not installable or
                                        postgresql-9.3-debversion but it is 
not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Edit: For clarification, when I run `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`, there are no held packages. The system is completely up to date. Running it through `aptitude` doesn't fix anything, as the only solution it offers is to keep everything at the current version (so basically not installed).

Comment: @chaNcharge Nope, tried everything in that thread and nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out on my own. The issue ended up being that `python-convoy` (one of `landscape-server`'s dependencies) couldn't be installed, so I decided to manually install it. I ran `wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/convoy/python-convoy_0.2.1+bzr39-1_all.deb` and `dpkg -i python-convoy_0.2.1+bzr39-1_all.deb`. Since `landscape-server` requires at least version 0.4.1, I ran `sudo apt upgrade` in order to upgrade it to that version. I then ran `sudo apt install landscape-server-quickstart`, and everything installed perfectly. All I had left to do was set up Landscape, which was fairly painless.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, to get around this problem, is to enable the 'universe' repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Comment: Universe repository can't magically remove dependency issues.

Comment: This is correct. But in this case, the missing packages are in the universe repository. At least this was the problem in my case and I had the same error message.